# How to dynamically change the column width in ListView WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i am writing WPF application. I have a simple UserControl containing ListView. ListView contains three columns. I would like to dynamically change width of the middle column depending on the UserControl size, i need to fill the whole UserControl with the list. Here's my xaml code:

```
<UserControl 
             ...
             d:DesignHeight="540" 
             d:DesignWidth="750">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Converters:ItemTypeToImageConverter x:Key="ItemTypeToImageConverter"/>
        <Converters:ListWidthMultiConverter x:Key="ListWidthMultiConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <ListView
            MinWidth="750"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MainListItemStyle}"
            Background="{StaticResource LightBackgroundBrush}"
            BorderThickness="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}"
            SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView
                    AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                    <GridViewColumn Width="50">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainListItemVM}">
                                <Image
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Width="30"
                                    Height="30"
                                    Source="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource ItemTypeToImageConverter}}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}">
                        <GridViewColumn.Width>
                            <MultiBinding 
                                Converter="{StaticResource ListWidthMultiConverter}">
                                <Binding 
                                    Path="ActualWidth"
                                    RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}"/>
                                <Binding
                                    Path="View.Columns"
                                    RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </GridViewColumn.Width>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Size}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here's my Converter code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Controls;


    public class ListWidthMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            double userControlWidth = 750;
            double columnsWidth = 750;
            var columns = values[1] as IList<GridViewColumn>;

            if (double.TryParse(values[0].ToString(), out userControlWidth) && columns != null)
            {

                columnsWidth = columns[0].Width + columns[2].Width;

            }

            double returnValue = userControlWidth - columnsWidth;

            return returnValue > 0 ? returnValue : 0;

        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    }
```

The converter calculates width properly, but nothing happens on a screen. Despite returning correct value (550), the width of the middle column in the view is definitely 0. That's not the only problem; when i'm trying to run this code, there is very high demand on computing power. Application starts to work so slowly, that it's impossible to use it. There must be some problem with the converter or xaml code, because if i cut it, add replace the width with constant value, everything seems to be correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The calculation done in the converter can be done directly in the ViewModel and the binding should be done directly from column Width to the property in Datacontext. Also,it appears that the conserned column should be puted in a Datatemplate in the ListView resources to dynamicly apply the width at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way i was trying to achieve that was quite complicated. Here's much better solution (working properly). In code behind file you need to have something like this:

```
        public DirectoryContentList()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            Application.Current.MainWindow.SizeChanged += ResizeNameColumn;

        }

        private void ResizeNameColumn(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs args)
        {

            var newWidth = Application.Current.MainWindow.ActualWidth - (TypeColumn.Width + SizeColumn.Width + 290);
            NameColumn.Width = newWidth > 0 ?  newWidth :  0; //Cannot set negative value to the column width

        }
```

Firstly try to name columns in xaml file, then change the width manually in code behind.